# Not able to create schema in Synapse Lake database using SPARK

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Tried below query to create schema using synapse spark notebook, but instead of creating Schema its creating another lake database.

```
%%sql 
 **CREATE SCHEMA Test**
```

How can we create different schemas in a single lake database?

Answer (score 1):

Create Schema is different to create schema in for example SQL Server. In Spark SQL, [Create Database and Schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-database.html) is the same thing.

In terms of Spark, you can just create the table with the name for example 'test_someTableNameGoesHere' with 'test' being the schema which should meet your database.schema.table/view requirements. Normally Spark/Databrick notation is around (schema/database.table) or 'catalog.(schema/database).table'

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is the way to get this work done. I have already proposed this solution.